# How can I create a region cache in gem5

Tags: python, c++, caching, memory-management, gem5

Im trying to modify the ~/src/mem/cache/ scripts and code to make a region base cache system for the ARM architecture. so far I have managed to change the SConscript so that a copy of cache.cc,cache.hh and Cache.py is built in the scons but I dont know where I should redirect the memory accessees to the region caches. In other words: I want to be able to direct some mem ref.s based on their mem. address to access D-cacheA and the rest to D-cacheB while cache A & B are the same.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are trying to track misses to a phyAddr across cache levels. I think you can do that by modifying appropriate Request/Response in /src/mem/protocol/*-msg.sm